# Possible to create Fat32 Filesystem with 512 Byte Allocation unit size?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, partitioning, 64-bit

When right clicking my harddirve within my computer, I have a format option.
Inside the format window I have a list called *Allocation Unit Size* which has entries

- 2048 bytes
- 4096 bytes
- 8192 byes
- 16 kilobytes
- 32 kilobytes
- 64 kilobytes

The problem is, I need 512 bytes as when trying to run another cmd on the harddrive, I am told the Allocation MUST be 512 bytes - yet there doesnt exist such option.

The other cmd I am running as admin within cmd prompt is

```
bootsect.exe /nt60 G:
```

which returns error

```
FAT32 filesystem bootcode is only supported on hardware with 512 byte
sector sizes.

No bootcode was successfully updated.
```

I am on Windows 7 professional 64 bit

**UPDATE**

When using *Disk Management* in a 32 bit Windows XP enviroment, After deleting all partitions and creating a new one, I have the option to select 512 Allocation Unit size.
However when applying this and waiting for the format to finish, at 100% I get the error message.

```
the cluster size is too small for the selected file system.
```

Comment: Cluster size is not sector size. if the drive is an advanced format real 4096 byte sector drive it will never have 512byte sectors, reguardless of the cluster arrangment. Sectors tend to be the hardware, although the disk own controller, or added disk controllers can "translate" this to  "fix" other issues, like size.  What is the disk? most of the 4096 sector disk present themselves as 512byte anyways to the system?

Comment: @Psycogeek I have tried with 2 portable Use Harddrives, one Samsung 500GB, one toshiba 1 TB

Comment: ok well the problem is not the cluster size, it is also unlikely to be the disk items, it could be the controller for those disk items?  Because of the lack of information about this particular error on the web, it might be useful to describe, first what your trying to have as an end results, then possibly there are other ways or other tools that would do that easier or with less problems? I do not know.

Comment: @Psycogeek I am trying to install windows 8.1 on a mac, using the tutorial http://bootableusb.net/make-bootable-external-hdd-install-windows-78 Everything works fine apart up until the cmd I mentioned above